# Why the storage of Documents showing wrong in mac?

Tags: macos, mac, storage

macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6

I recently removed some of the large files in my mac and checked the storage.

I'm shocked to see this. The Documents folder in which all my files and other folders were kept is 32.39GB.

But in the main Documents I see 129.47GB. Please see the following image.

[image]

Initially I searched for this problem and found this [Spotlight doesn't work anymore in OS X Mountain Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/83958/spotlight-doesnt-work-anymore-in-os-x-mountain-lion/108557#108557)

I did that, but it didn't work.

Any help is appreciated. thanq

Comment: hi, what view is that ? I can not get my Finder to show it.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Click About this Mac -> Click Storage -> Click Manage -> Click Documents

Comment: Got it, thank you, see my answer for what I understand what it shows

Answer (score 11):

I was searching for this question. why the summary tell different size with the "actual size calculation"
then I realize, maybe there something like some hidden folder in the calculation.
with this idea, I came up to try to show the hidden files.

so, I press shortcut "<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>period</kbd>" and all the hidden folders is shown. It came up with the Library folder, which has almost half of the calculated size and another folder.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It now shows all hidden folders in Documents - File Browser (Storege Management)

Comment: This is the answer that solved it for me. Chrome had many hidden downloads taking up a ton of space. ".com.google.Chrome."<some_hash> 60 Gigs worth. My system can now take the next OS update. :)

Answer (score 8):

The System Information view is misleading by naming it "Documents"

Under the category "Documents" it will trow everything in in that is not in the other sidebar listed categories.

For example in my case, it will show all my Movies as Documents.

The misunderstood display .. it says my "Documents" are 92GB which is not true for Documents Folder.?

[image]

In your case....
[image]

Comment: The category Documents (129.47GB) has Documents (32.89GB), Pictures, Music, etc....if you sum up their memory it wont be 129.47GB. If you sum all those I guess it will be around 33 or 34 GB. How come the main category shows 129.47GB?

Comment: If you add all the memory in FileBrowser it should be size of Main category Documents. In my case it is not like that

Comment: Those numbers are not meant to represent the actual s, so do not try to add them. They represent categories, means some are in multiple categories.

Comment: ok I understand. And could you please tell how the Main category is 129GB? I'm not able to know how it 129GB

Comment: Also keep in mind, files that are not in either of these shown folders are also counted as a document "type". Check the Large files list and the downloads list.

Comment: I think it's because the filesystem indexing is working slow, I have the same issue, but after reboot and wait a few minutes...., it shows the reasonable size.

Answer (score 2):

You placed a screenshot of the The `Storage Management.app`. This particular utility shows a categorized view of your disk contents.

**What is Storage Management App**

`Storage Management.app` is a utility app which gives you an overall perspective of what do you have in your system. Whether its loaded with applications or iOS Backups or Books or you haven't simply emptied your trash. It's not misleading, it is the way it is designed.

It categorized several file types as `Documents` e.g. xip, zip, dmg, mov and even unknown file types etc. Most of these file types are larger in file sizes.

If you want to see how much each folder on disk is taking space, you should use `Finder > Get Info` to see what you're looking for.